# use global config object in react app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have config.js file defined by generator;

```
'use strict';

import baseConfig from './base';

let config = {
  appEnv: 'dev',  // feel free to remove the appEnv property here,
  baseUrl:'https://mod970274.sharepoint.com',//'http://maliye.milliemlak.gov.tr',
  listName:''
};

export default Object.freeze(Object.assign({}, baseConfig, config));
```

and here how I call it.

```
import config from 'config';

class FooterState {
    @observable items =[];
    constructor(){
        config.listName = 'FooterMenu';
        this.getItems();
    }
    getItems() {
  fetch(`${config.baseUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${config.listName}')/items`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
```

but eventhough using examples looks same it throws undefined exception in constructor. this is how it looks:

[image]

how can I use config object everywhere in project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export default Object.freeze(Object.assign({}, baseConfig, config));
```

This line [freezes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) the object, which means you can't reassign any of its properties:

> The Object.freeze() method freezes an object: that is, prevents new properties from being added to it; prevents existing properties from being removed; and prevents existing properties, or their enumerability, configurability, or writability, from being changed.  The method returns the object being frozen.

If you want to change the data on this object, you should remove the Object.freeze:

```
export default Object.assign({}, baseConfig, config) // Or just: export default {...baseConfig, ...config}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your config object is frozen:

```
export default Object.freeze(Object.assign({}, baseConfig, config));
```

Therefore you cannot modify it. Now you have two options:

1. remove the call to `Object.freeze` in `config.js`
2. if you cannot modify `config.js`, define your own mutable derived config object with `Object.assign()`:

_

```
/* mutable-config.js */
import config from 'config'
module.exports = Object.assign({}, config)
```

Now you can use `mutable-config` instead of `config` in your code:

```
import config from 'mutable-config' /* instead of from `config` */

class FooterState {
    @observable items =[];
[...]
```